# Are revolving logs on AppEngine based on number of entries or size of entries?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I'd like to print some more debug information to my log entries. However, I don't want to have less historic logs as a result.

Does appengine's logging system revolve logs based on the number of entries (i.e. it only stores the last 1000 log entries) or is it based on storage size (i.e. it only stores the last 100MB worth of log data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine has separate log buffers for each log level - debug, warn, error etc - and each one is a fixed size in bytes. As you write more logs at a given level, older entries at that level will be erased to make room.